How to catch "System.UnexpectedException: Unable to fetch the OAuth token."
I have a Queueable class that makes a callout using Named Credentials. Sometimes I get
System.UnexpectedException: Unable to fetch the OAuth token.

I surrounded the send method with try/catch block
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:NamedCredName');
request.setMethod('GET');
HttpResponse response;
try {
    response = new Http().send(request);
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n --- callout - error ---'
    +'\n - e.getCause(): ' + e.getCause()
    +'\n - e.getMessage(): ' + e.getMessage()
    +'\n');
} catch(System.UnexpectedException ue) {
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '\n\n --- callout - error ---'
    +'\n - ue.getCause(): ' + ue.getCause()
    +'\n - ue.getMessage(): ' + ue.getMessage()
    +'\n');
}
if (response == null) {
    // this one is not executed in case of the exception
}

The try/catch blocks don't help.
I have Send Apex Warning Emails flag set in my User - doesn't help.
My desire is to get notified via Email about this error.
The problem is that if the same request is executed in a second after seeing this error it will work. So I would like to have a notify/re-try mechanism specifically for this Exception.

I am afraid there is no graceful way to handle this exception - check https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387856&type=1. Maybe finalizers can help in this usecase - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm

@kurunve, in my particular way it solves my problem. The finalizer does the job. Thanks! Please post your comment as answer I'll accept it.

Why don't you use Nebula Logger which supports recording of most Apex logs including Queueable jobs.
Basically you just install the unlocked package to your sandbox.
Then call the Logger method as in the readme :
    Logger.setParentLogTransactionId(this.parentLogTransactionId);
    Logger.fine('queueableContext==' + queueableContext);
    Logger.info('this.numberOfJobsToChain==' + this.numberOfJobsToChain);
    Logger.info('this.parentLogTransactionId==' + this.parentLogTransactionId);

    // Add your queueable job's logic here

    Logger.saveLog();

Then go to the 'Logs' Tab to see your logs.

I like finalizer option more - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm It is enough for my particular case.

I've struggled with this exception - it happened when named credential becomes invalid.
You can't cach an unexpected exception. The execution thread will abort immediately.
However it's possible to recover, when you are working within a quable.
If you take a look at apex transaction finalizer. getException() also handles those exceptions.
However you have to persist all data that is sent in the request (sobject) to be able to do that. Dan appleman has a chapter in his advanced apex book about it.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm
